# How to disable “Transform to” option in Gutenberg custom blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I prepared some non-standard Gutenberg blocks.
They have a very specific purpose.

Therefore, I do not want them to have the `Transform to` option available.

What I found is the ability to use `support: {}`, but I can only disable *Add to Reusable blocks* there.

Can this Transform option be blocked too? I can't find any information in Block Editor Handbook

By picturing, I mean this option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The selector [getBlockTransformItems](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor/#getblocktransformitems) from the Block Editor's data determines which options are shown in "Transform To". If no transforms are defined in `registerBlockType()`, it picks the most common block that any block could be transformed to (a group or columns containing the block). If you provide your own transform, it will be displayed and not display group or columns.

At present, there doesn't seem to be a way to completely disable it, but there is an [open issue on this topic](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/31905) on Gutenberg.